# JQuery Lower Case Text

Tags: jquery, css

I have many fields containing data from the database.  The text is all cap!

I have tried `text-transform: capitalize;` The first letter is already uppercase and this CSS cannot lower the rest of letters.  Then I add 1 more class `text-transform: lowercase;`, it will take either one.

I am planing to use JQuery to lower all the text and then use CSS to do capitalize.

Somehow my JQuery syntax doesn't work out.  Please help.  [LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/5gx4c35g/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
$('#tester').val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
    });
```

Comment: You're trying to grab a value on an element that has no value. Look into `text()`.

Comment: So why does the CSS `text-transform:lowercase;` not work for you? I'm unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<div>` does not have a value, therefore you cannot use `.val()`! Use `html()`, or `text()` instead:

```
$(function() {
var test = $('#tester')
test.html(test.html().toLowerCase());
});
```

## <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gx4c35g/3/)</kbd>

Comment: @ Imagine WebDesign, Thank you very much, but I replaced `$('#tester').html($(this).html().toLowerCase());` it doesn't work!  I wonder how comes?

Comment: @abcidd the `$(this).html()` is what is messing it up change it to `$('#tester')` or create a var of `#tester` and use it like `var test = $('#tester');` `test.html()`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to convert the text to lowercase, use JavaScript.

```js
var tester = document.getElementById('tester');
tester.innerHTML = tester.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
```

```html
<div id="tester">HTHT HTHTRH HTH RTGHWS HTHT NBGB S</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, chipChocolate.py so much!  Wow, there is another way to do it!

Comment: @abcidd - Well, ofcourse there is. Loading a whole jQuery library just to convert the text to lowercase is an overkill. I'd say use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with `this` scope that reference window.

Try this:

```js
var $tester = $('#tester');    
$tester.text($tester.text().toLowerCase());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div id="tester">HTHT HTHTRH HTH RTGHWS HTHT NBGB S</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `this` is actually the `window`. Also `val()` is used for form controls to set/get value

You can use `text(function)` to do it:

```
$('#tester').text(function(_, val){
    return val.toLowerCase();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2n4q9g4z/)**</kbd>

Comment: @ charlietfl, Thank you very much!  I try to replace  `.val(function(_, val){
    return val.toLowerCase();` but it doesn't work, either!

Comment: sorry, I copy pasted your code to modify and left `val()` in. Fixed with working demo also

Answer (score 0):

Replace "$(this)" with "$('#tester')"

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
$('#tester').val($('#tester').val().toLowerCase());
    });
```

In that context, "this" doesn't refer to '#tester'